# Finding/replacing values for a specific column in Notepad++

Tags: regex, notepad++

I think I need RegEx for this, but it is new to me...

What I have in a text file are 200 rows of data, 100 INSERT INTO rows and 100 corresponding VALUE rows.

So it looks like this:

```
INSERT INTO DB1.Tbl1 (Col1, Col2, Col3........Col20)
VALUES(123, 'ABC', '201450204 15:37:48'........'DEF')
```

What I want to do is replace every Date/Timestamp value in Col3 with this: CURRENT_TIMESTAMP.  The Date/Timestamps are NOT the same for every row.  They differ, but they are all in Column 3.

There are 100 records in this table, some other tables have more, that's why I am looking for a shortcut to do this.

Comment: This is SQL code for a database... Not sure how this is relevant to Notepad++ or regex.

Comment: You would probably be better served by actually spinning up a SQL server of some kind. Doing this in regex will be tricky unless you can be sure that the first two columns will be free of "special characters" (e.g. commas, single quotes).

Comment: `201450204` what kind of date is that? looks alien

Comment: if you have only single date/timestamp column, then you can replace `'\d{8} \d\d:\d\d:\d\d'` regex with `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`.

Comment: If you want to update that file, in order to run it against the database, it might be easier, to execute the pile of statements, and then `UPDATE` "Col3". If there is already some data in "DB1.Tbl1", for which the timestamp must not be updated, and there is no criterion, which sets apart the data in your batch (to be used for the `UPDATE`'s `WHERE`), consider a temporary table. You could use the temporary table for the import and update, and then issue `INSERT INTO DB1.Tbl1 [column list as needed] SELECT * FROM TempTable`. Check back if you need more detail.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this:**

search with `(INSERT[^,]+,[^,]+,)([^,]+,)([^']+'[^']+'[^']+)('[^']+',)`  and replace with `$1$3` and check mark regular expression in the notepad++

[Live demo](https://regex101.com/r/tD9yT5/1)

Answer (score 0):

With

- "VALUES" being right at the beginning of the line,
- "Col1" values being all numeric, and
- no single quotes inside the values for "Col2"

you can search for

```
^(VALUES\(\d+, '[^']+', )'(\d{9} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2})'
```

and replace with

```
\1CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```

along [RegEx101](https://regex101.com/r/xH4kC7/1). (Remember, Notepad++ uses the backslash in the replacement string…)

Personally, I'd consider to go straight to the database, and fix the timestamp there - especially, if you have more data to handle. (See my above comment for the general idea.)

Please comment, if and as further detail / adjustment is required.